# Efficient way to create pairs of all combinations of column names as a rows in a data.frame

Tags: r, matrix

I have this data.frame in R:

```
df = data.frame("blue" = c(0,1,1,0,1),
                "yellow" = c(0,0,1,0,1),
                "green" = c(1,1,1,0,0),
                "letter" = c("A","B","C","D","E"),
                "id" = c(23,57,48,3,12))
```

```
  blue yellow green Letter ID
1    0      0     1      A 23
2    1      0     1      B 57
3    1      1     1      C 48
4    0      0     0      D  3
5    1      1     0      E 12
```

and would like to turn it into a data frame with all possible combinations of colors (colnames to rows), maintaining the Letter and ID of each pair, like in here:

```
   Col_1    Col_2    C1  C2  Letter  ID
1  blue     yellow   0   0   A       23
2  blue     green    0   1   A       23
3  yellow   green    0   1   A       23
4  blue     yellow   1   0   B       57
5  blue     green    1   1   B       57
6  yellow   green    0   1   B       57
7  blue     yellow   1   1   C       48
8  blue     green    1   1   C       48
9  yellow   green    1   1   C       48
10 blue     yellow   0   1   D       3
11 blue     green    0   0   D       3
12 yellow   green    1   0   D       3
13 blue     yellow   1   1   E       12
14 blue     green    1   0   E       12
15 yellow   green    1   0   E       12
```

Since my database is huge doing so with loops is taking too long. Any suggestions to do it more efficiently?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a `data.table` solution using `melt` that should work well unless the database is absolutely massive, in which case you can always split it by ID, but I'd guess this works fast for your case.

```
library(data.table)
df = data.frame("blue" = c(0,1,1,0,1),
                "yellow" = c(0,0,1,0,1),
                "green" = c(1,1,1,0,0),
                "letter" = c("A","B","C","D","E"),
                "id" = c(23,57,48,3,12))

#convert to data.table and melt
setDT(df)

df = melt(df, id.vars = c("letter","id"))

#combine blue/yellow, blue/green, and yellow/green
df1 = merge(df[variable == "blue"],df[variable == "yellow"], by = c("letter","id"))
df2 = merge(df[variable == "blue"],df[variable == "green"], by = c("letter","id"))
df3 = merge(df[variable == "yellow"],df[variable == "green"], by = c("letter","id"))

df = rbindlist(list(df1,df2,df3))

#now fix names..
setnames(df, c("variable.x","value.x","variable.y","value.y"), c("col_1","c1","col_2","c2"))

#optionally rearrange cols...
df = df[,.(col_1,col_2,c1,c2,letter,id)]
```

Comment: Thanks, that was very helpful. I added the `df1 <- merge(df[variable == "blue"],df[variable == "yellow"], by = c("letter","id"))` in a loop with the "blue" and "yellow" being rows of my list off all possible 600 combinations (`list[i,1] and list[i,2]`) and it took 5+ minutes to run.

Comment: not exactly sure what you mean by "'blue' and 'yellow' being rows of my list off all possible 600 combinations", but glad it helped :)

Comment: Just indexed color names from other data frame created using `combn()` with all the color names instead of spelling all combinations myself at the code

Answer (score 0):

Consider following `base` solution to dynamically fit any needed set of values:

**Data**

```
txt <- '  blue yellow green Letter ID
1    0      0     1      A 23
2    1      0     1      B 57
3    1      1     1      C 48
4    0      0     0      D  3
5    1      1     0      E 12'

df <- read.table(text = txt, header=TRUE)
```

**Solution**

```
# DEFINE VECTOR OF VALUES 
vals <- c("blue", "yellow", "green")

# RESHAPE DATA LONG
rdf <- reshape(df, idvar = c("Letter", "ID"), 
               varying = vals, times = vals, 
               v.names = "C", timevar = "Col1", ids = NULL,
               new.row.names = 1:1E4, direction = "long")

# HELPER DF FOR ALL POSSIBLE COMBNS (AVOID REVERSE DUPLICATES)
col_df <- subset(expand.grid(Col1 = vals, Col2 = vals,
                             stringsAsFactors = FALSE),
                 Col1 < Col2)

# MERGE TWICE FOR EACH SET OF COLs
mdf <- merge(merge(rdf, col_df, by.x="Col1", by.y="Col1"), rdf, 
             by.x=c("Letter", "ID", "Col2"),
             by.y=c("Letter", "ID", "Col1"),
             suffixes = c(1, 2))

# RE-ORDER ROWS AND COLUMNS
mdf <- data.frame(with(mdf, mdf[order(Letter, ID), 
                                c("Letter", "ID", "Col1", "Col2", "C1", "C2")]), 
                  row.names = NULL)
```

**Output**

```
mdf

#    Letter ID  Col1   Col2 C1 C2
# 1       A 23  blue  green  0  1
# 2       A 23  blue yellow  0  0
# 3       A 23 green yellow  1  0
# 4       B 57  blue  green  1  1
# 5       B 57 green yellow  1  0
# 6       B 57  blue yellow  1  0
# 7       C 48  blue  green  1  1
# 8       C 48 green yellow  1  1
# 9       C 48  blue yellow  1  1
# 10      D  3  blue  green  0  0
# 11      D  3 green yellow  0  0
# 12      D  3  blue yellow  0  0
# 13      E 12  blue  green  1  0
# 14      E 12  blue yellow  1  1
# 15      E 12 green yellow  0  1
```

---

The known bottleneck is possibly the `base::reshape` for very large data frames. Here is a faster function using matrix manipulation:

```
matrix_melt <- function(df1, key, indName, valName) {
  value_cols <- names(df1)[ !(names(df1) %in% key)]
  mat_inds <- matrix(matrix(value_cols, nrow=nrow(df1), ncol=ncol(df1)-2, byrow=TRUE), ncol=1)
  mat_vals <- matrix(df1[value_cols], ncol= 1, byrow = TRUE)

  df2 <- setNames(data.frame(df1[key], unlist(mat_inds), unlist(mat_vals), 
                             row.names = NULL, stringsAsFactors = FALSE),
                  c(key, indName, valName))
  return(df2)
}

rdf <- matrix_melt(df, c("Letter", "ID"), "Col1", "C")
rdf
```